# CocoaPods AFnetworkign 2.0 install issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I try to install via CocoaPods AFNetworking 2.0 but got this message

```
[!] Invalid `AFNetworking.podspec` file: undefined method `social_media_url=' for #<Pod::Specification name="AFNetworking">. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

 #  from /Users/mac/.cocoapods/repos/master/AFNetworking/2.2.0/AFNetworking.podspec:7
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    s.homepage = 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking'
 >    s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/AFNetworking'
 #    s.authors  = { 'Mattt Thompson' => 'm@mattt.me' }
```

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jervine10 said you need to update CocoaPods. `[sudo] gem install cocoapods`

Edit: It's also worth noting that until CocoaPods reaches 1.0 changes are made very quickly. It's always worth making sure you're up to date when you're having issues.